# Conversion of Protobuf Byte [] to ProtoBuf Compiled Class

Tags: java, arrays, protocol-buffers, messaging

I am working on to receive an incoming message in the form of protobuf byte [] and my method would be to convert it into a protobuf compiled class before I proceed with converting it into JSON format.

Below are the Code Snippets which I had currently and I would appreciate if anyone could advise me on what are the areas which I should be rectifying on.

```
public void conversionMethod(byte[] inputMessage) {
     
    try {
    
    byte[] wrapperMessage = inputMessage;
    
    Any any = Any.parseFrom(wrapperMessage);
    
    
    if (any.is(Teacher.class))
    {
      TeacherProto teacherProto = any.unpack(TeacherProto.class);
     
    } 
    
    
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    
}
```

I am following the guide in this link, **https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/java/com/google/protobuf/Any** as a reference at the moment.

Currently I am shown this error at the moment.

```
The method is(Class<T>) in the type Any is not applicable
for the arguments (Class<ElevatorProto>)
```

What can I try to solve this?

Comment: The compiler error message does not match your example code.  Please provide an **accurate** [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that we can understand what the real problem is.

Answer (score -1):

I don't think what you are trying to do is practical.

First of all, a protobuf message contains only field numbers, wire types and encoded values.  There are only 6 wire types:

- 0     Varint  int32, int64, uint32, uint64, sint32, sint64, bool, enum
- 1     64-bit  fixed64, sfixed64, double
- 2     Length-delimited    string, bytes, embedded messages, packed repeated fields
- 3     Start group     groups (deprecated)
- 4     End group   groups (deprecated)
- 5     32-bit

That is not sufficient to reconstruct the field names and types for a Java class.

I don't think that using `Any` probably will work either.  According to [this](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#any), and `Any` doesn't actually contain a descriptor for the *type* of the packed value.  Instead, it contains ...

> ... a URL that acts as a globally unique identifier for and resolves to that message's type.

But AFAIK that URL is *just* used as an identifier for a protobuf type that the receiver already knows about.  It doesn't contain the information needed to construct the (actual) message ... in order to generate a Java class.

---

**UPDATE** - This probably won't help you, but according to comments in the Google "Any.proto" definition, it might be possible to implement a type resolver.

```
  // In practice, teams usually precompile into the binary all types that they
  // expect it to use in the context of Any. However, for URLs which use the
  // scheme `http`, `https`, or no scheme, one can optionally set up a type
  // server that maps type URLs to message definitions as follows:
  //
  // * If no scheme is provided, `https` is assumed.
  // * An HTTP GET on the URL must yield a [google.protobuf.Type][]
  //   value in binary format, or produce an error.
  // * Applications are allowed to cache lookup results based on the
  //   URL, or have them precompiled into a binary to avoid any
  //   lookup. Therefore, binary compatibility needs to be preserved
  //   on changes to types. (Use versioned type names to manage
  //   breaking changes.)
  //
  // Note: this functionality is not currently available in the official
  // protobuf release, and it is not used for type URLs beginning with
  // type.googleapis.com.
```

So ... you could set up your own type server to publish the definitions of your message types.  You could (I guess) use those definitions to generate the protobuf classes, or you could generate the JSON in a more dynamic fashion.

But the above implies at least some part of your "organization" knows about and publishes the types.  So why not just get hold of all of the published types and use them to generate the corresponding protobuf classes each time that you rebuild your application?  Or, why not maintenance of a library of protobuf classes the responsibility of the group that publishes the types?

(OK.  I can see why you might want your application to be more dynamic than those ideas would be.  But is it worth the extra effort and complexity?)